# "intend that ..." vs "intend for"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

- I intended that the sentence means "*Meaning Of The Sentence Comes Here"*.
- I intended for the sentence to mean "*Meaning Of The Sentence Comes Here"*.

Are above sentences correct and natural?
What I want to mean by the above sentences is:

- The previous sentence I said/wrote is intended to mean "*Meaning Of The Sentence Comes Here"*.

Comment: ***I intend that...*** would normally be followed by a "subjunctive" clause outlining the intended future scenario: *I intend that **my daughter SHOULD MARRY a millionaire.*** But ***I intend for...*** is normally followed by an "infinitive-based" clause: *I intend for **my daughter TO MARRY a millionaire.*** It's purely a stylistic choice in your context whether to say ***...that the sentence should mean...*** or ***...for the sentence to mean...*** (where ***for*** is optional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say

- " I intended the sentence to mean "Meaning Of The Sentence Comes Here" omitting "for"".

That would be also OK to say

- "I intended to mean "Meaning Of The Sentence Comes Here" by the sentence I just wrote. "